# MUI React - How is the theme able to respond to a mode change after being set with useMediaQuery()?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

As per [the MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#system-preference), to make the site theme follow the browser/system default, you check the match on a media query (`prefers-color-scheme: dark`) with their `useMediaQuery()` hook, and you put that into your theme object and feed it into a `ThemeProvider` that you wrap the rest of the app with.
It all works just fine, but I have one question about it: How is it able to update as you change your desired theme (e.g. by messing with Windows colour settings)?
Take this code snippet:

```
function App() {
    const preferredMode: PaletteMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)') ? 'dark' : 'light';

    const theme = createTheme(
        {
            palette: {
                mode: preferredMode
            }
        }
    );

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            /* Rest of the app */
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Why does it re-render in such a scenario? (causing the theme to regenerate and all MUI components to switch to the other mode)
This isn't unwanted behaviour in any way, I'm just not able to understand it and it annoys me to no end.